# Identifying handheld radio speaker components

Tags: capacitor, diodes, radio, wire

I have a handheld radio (com) that looks to have a bad speaker. I am trying to determine what the white elements are on the speaker terminals and how to replace them at the same time.

Are they diodes, or capacitors, or something else?

They are unmarked and I have not been able to find info about why both the positive and negative terminals would have one.

I thought it would not make sense to replace just the speaker in case one or both of those are bad.

[image]

Comment: What are the symptoms?

Comment: The audio output from this radio speaker is too low and distorted.

Comment: It does not necessarily mean it's the speaker that's damaged. The white beads are likely ferrite beads for EMI suppression or just some ceramic spacer for extra insulation. Likely the wire just goes through the white bead and is not broken. You can freely use a multimeter and beads should read nearly zero ohms. You can try another speaker but it likely is not the issue.

Comment: Might as well by something in the RF/audio path causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- They are not capacitors. They are physically too small for the capacitance to be of any use in series with an eight ohm speaker.
- They are not diodes.  A diode (let alone two) in series with a speaker is pointless - unless it is part of a distortion circuit made to intentionally mangle the audio for musical purposes.

Those might be some kind of inductor, but I doubt it. If they are inductors then they'll most likely be ferrite beads.

They may be simple jumper wires.

Whether jumpers or ferrite bead inductors, it is unlikely they are the source of the problems.  Those parts would show obvious signs of damage (cracked, broken, burned) if they were bad.

---

Disconnect (unsolder) one end of each of the two white things, then use an ohmmeter to test the resistance.  They should both measure near zero ohms.

Comment: If they are jumper wires, the white barrel is there to simplify the manufacturing process. "Zero Ohm Resistors" are a standard part for this reason.

Comment: Through hole ferrite beads are often without any marking.